# Does this text resembles any script language?

Tags: printing, scripting-language

According to a laboratory instrument (OS: windows 2000) manufacturer's guidelines , result print format can be edited with an limited set of operators an tags like:

```
@PATNUM/14  Patient identification number
@PATNAM/33  Patient name
@SSEX/1     Patient sex
@AGE/4  Patient age
@BIRDAT2/8  Date of birth
@SSTTUS/1   Patient status (in or out)
@ADDAD1/31  Patient address
@ADDAD2/31  Second line for the patient address
@CPCOM/5    Patient coded comment
@TPCOM/30   Patient comment
@FILESTS/29     Status of the selected sample
@SELDT/43   Date and time of the selected period
@PAGNUM/4   Keyword generating the page number when the list is printed
#   Allows a form feed
!   Indicates the vertical and horizontal position of the tests and results.
>   Indicates the beginning of the next result character string. Do not use it if you want one test per line.
*   Indicates the beginning of the patient and sample information area (mandatory entry).
**  Indicates the beginning of the result area (mandatory entry).
***     Indicates the beginning of the page bottom (mandatory entry).
```

and a sample format can be like:

```
TEST      RESULT  ABN       NORMALS         UNITS
*RESCOM
WBC       @WBC          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
RBC       @RBC          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
HGB       @HGB          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
HCT       @HCT          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
MCV       @MCV          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
MCH       @MCH          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
MCHC      @MCHC         ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
CHCM      @CHCM         ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
CH        @CH           ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
RDW       @RDW          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
HDW       @HDW          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
PLT       @PLT          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
MPV       @MPV          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....

%NEUT     @%NEUT        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
%LYMPH    @%LYMPH       ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
%MONO     @%MONO        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
%EOS      @%EOS         ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
%BASO     @%BASO        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
%LUC      @%LUC         ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
%NRBC     @%NRBC        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#NEUT     @#NEUT        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#LYMPH    @#LYMPH       ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#MONO     @#MONO        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#EOS      @#EOS         ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#BASO     @#BASO        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#LUC      @#LUC         ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#NRBC     @#NRBC        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....

%RETIC    @%RETIC       ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
#RETIC    @#RETIC       ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
MCVr      @MCVr         ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
CHCMr     @CHCMr        ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
CHr       @CHr          ( @LOW.- @HIGH  )  @UNITS....
```

Instrument printouts are according to this format.
The problem is that I need to have color text in printed results and the instrument instruction manual don't have any useful information in this matter.
I wondered if this script is not instrument specific and is a kind of scripting language I don't know.

Does it looks like any scripting language?

Comment: This looks like a format *declaration*. "Declarative" formats are opposed to languages for forming Turing-complete executable expressions (i.e. a programming/scripting language).

Comment: @Dai is it closable under flag ?